# Make jQuery library load before plugin files

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I am using a few jQuery plugins such as validate.js, but they all load BEFORE the Jquery library which is loaded automatically by WordPress and my theme.

I need the plugins to load after - so is there a way to make Jquery load first in functions.php - so that I can use it frontend and admin.

I am currently loading the following in functions.php

```
wp_enqueue_script('validation',
get_bloginfo('template_url') ."/js/jquery.validate.min.js");

wp_enqueue_script('scripts',
get_bloginfo('template_url') ."/js/scripts.js");
```

Any help, massively appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look at the `wp_enqueue_script` [Codex Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script), you'll see one of the options is `$deps`, this would mean that your script is dependent upon another script, simply add **jquery** as a dependancy and your scripts will load in the correct place.

If you set a handle for the other scripts you can use them as a dependent as well.

Example:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 
    'your-handle', 
    get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/path/script.js', 
    array( 'jquery' ) 
);
```

Comment: Cheers JK - seemed to get it working by simply ordering it in functions.php - yet when I tried it the first time it didn't work. Using dependencies is definitely the way to go!