# Removing jQuery from footer

Tags: jquery, footer

I am working with [HTML5 Blank](http://html5blank.com/) and I can't seem to get jquery to stop being called in wp_footer(). I have tried adding this to the bottom of my functions file:

```
function theme_slug_dequeue_footer_jquery() {
 wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery' );
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'theme_slug_dequeue_footer_jquery', 11 );
```

with no luck. I also tried:

```
if( !is_admin()){
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_dequeue_script('jquery');}
```

but I still end up with `/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3` being called in the footer. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just to get you right: don't you want jQuery being enqueued at all, or do you just want it to be enqueued in the header rather than in the footer?

Comment: Do you know what is enqueuing the script? If you dequeue this, whatever is using it could well stop working.

Comment: @tf I want it gone entirely. s_ha_dum: I'm not sure, but I am fine with that outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your working with a blank theme why don't you just remove or comment out the `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');` in the theme functions.php?

Otherwise your action hook is wrong, use,

```
add_action('wp_print_scripts','theme_slug_dequeue_footer_jquery');
function theme_slug_dequeue_footer_jquery() {
   wp_dequeue_script('jquery');
}
```

This will still load the build in jQuery (I think) in `/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3`

To remove all jQuery from the admin & the front end you have to `deregister_script`, this will break how the admin functions but it will still be usable (no drag and drop, etc).

```
add_action('wp_print_scripts','theme_slug_dequeue_footer_jquery');
function theme_slug_dequeue_footer_jquery() {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_dequeue_script('jquery');
    }
```

Also for just the front end use (this is the one you should be using):

```
 add_action('wp_print_scripts','theme_slug_dequeue_footer_jquery');
 function theme_slug_dequeue_footer_jquery() {
       if( !is_admin()){
           wp_dequeue_script('jquery');
       }
}
```

Comment: I tried your last block of code there but 1.8.3 is still being called in the footer :( The reason I wanted to do this was because I need to call an older version of jquery in the header before the main page content loads - maybe there is a better way than dequeueing?

Comment: No, disable plugins and switch to the default theme.

Comment: I see now that other includes in my functions file were calling jquery as a dependency ( this post helped http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/35039/27454 ) but your answer was also very helpful and technically correct based on the limited info I provided so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call another jQuery version, you could use the noConflict method and you can load them in header or footer with no problem in any order.